# How to refresh data in SSRS report accessed via ReportServer URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report that is accessed by users via the Web Service URL, we do this so we can pass in parameters.

e.g.

```
https://myserver.fqdn/ReportServer?/MyFolder/MyReport&rc:Toolbar=False&MyParameter=MyString
```

This works well the first time the report is accessed, but no amount of refreshing the browser will cause the data to refresh. I found I could fix this behavior by adding `rs:ClearSession=True` to the URL.

```
https://myserver.fqdn/ReportServer?/MyFolder/MyReport&rs:ClearSession=True&rc:Toolbar=False&myParameter=MyString
```

However this report also contains a number of `Go to report` actions. Clicking any of these actions strips the URL of the `rs:ClearSession=True` and now the reports contain old data.

Is there anyway to prevent the Web Service URL from doing any caching? This does not seem to be an issue when these reports are accessed via the Report Manager URL.

e.g.

```
https://myserver.fqdn/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMyFolder%2fMyReport
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the cache settings are set to 'Do not cache...'?

Comment: @BJones Yes, I have and that setting appears to be respected when accessed through the Report Manager URL, not so much when accessed via the Web Service URL.

Comment: How about if you click the refresh button within the report (assuming it's an available option)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the data to refresh by changing the value of a parameter.

You can exploit this by adding a hidden `Date/Time` parameter to each report. Within the `Go to report` action, assigning the new parameter a value of `=Now()` will change the value of this parameter each time the action is clicked.

This works even if you don't use the parameter in your report.